# Add a scheduled task to the GPO progrematically

Tags: powershell, group-policy

The assumption is I'm on a DC with admin rights. I want to add an immediate task to the GPO to run a .exe on the workstations, but I want to do it without the GUI i.e. quietly.

Is there a way to do this progrematically? Or in Powershell?

Comment: This is not an InfoSec question but a Windows Admin question.

Answer (score 0):

A GPO doesn't have a "run immediately" tool in it. However you can add things to the run once area, or the logon script area. Another spot to add executables to run is to the task scheduler. Another option is to install something from an MSI package. These can all be done without the user seeing anything on their screen. 
Can you give more details of what you are trying to accomplish?
Brian